# What is synonyme of "scale"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of the word "scale" in both cases?

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scale I couldn't find the appropriate meaning in the dictionary.

“For any new table reservations product, no matter how good it is, it’s very hard to get businesses to adopt the product at scale for two reasons. First, it is hard to scale a sales team without massive funding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word scale can have many meanings and can act as both noun and verb. [Source 1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scale)

In your case, for understanding the meaning of **at scale** in the first sentence, see [this thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116601/at-scale-definition).

In the second sentence, it is being used as a **phrasal verb** ([Source 2](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/scale-up)) and in this context, it means to *increase the size of the sales team*.

Comment: I think you're on the right track here, but unfortunately I can't find the meaning of scale in the OP in your Source 1.  The thread you reference is to this site and itself doesn't have any references to *scale*.  It discusses *at scale* and *scalability*.  The second sentence may be using *scale* to mean *scale up*, but it's only the latter that is a phrasal verb.

Comment: @deadrat Added an edit to indicate the linked thread shows the meaning of *at scale*. And yes I had made it clear that the second sentence uses a phrasal verb.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear.  Understanding the meaning of *at scale* might be important, but you don't say why, and *at scale* doesn't appear in the question.  In the second sentence, the verb is *scale*, one word.  So it's not phrasal.  Your answer has been accepted, so I won't comment further.

Comment: The OP wanted to know the meaning in both these sentences and hence I explained with respect to that context. **at scale** is used in the first sentence and in the second, it is **scale a sales team (*up* is implied here)** which is equivalent to *scale something up/down*.

Comment: You're right about the presence of *at scale*.