# What is the meaning of "Scale" here?

Tags: meaning

I've already asked question about this word on English stack exchange [What is synonyme of "scale"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286171/what-is-synonyme-of-scale)
But I guess there is some other meaning of it.

What does it mean in this case?

> In a lot of cases, the bigger a company gets the harder it is to actually find a way to contact support. Maybe remarkable support just doesn’t *scale*. But does it have to be this difficult to find an email address?

From http://blog.statuspage.io/customer-service-email

I tried to find an appropriate definition in the FreeDictionary and Cambridge dictionary, but it didn't help. Perhaps "doesn't scale" means "is not highly appreciated"?

Comment: It's in the sense that qualitative properties do not stay the same when the size of something increase notably. Look up for terms such as "scalable solutions".

Comment: In that case it means "remain remarkable when its size increases". The original, "doesn't scale" is jargon meaning "doesn't scale *up well*". The meaning of 'scale' as it is used there is 'grow larger or smaller', and it would usually (without jargon) be used with 'up' or 'down', as in 'scale up' or 'scale down'. In your jargon case, the 'up' is understood from the context ("bigger").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this sense, "scale" is part of the phrasal verb, *scale down* or *scale up*.

To say that something doesn't scale means that it either breaks under the weight of the full-scale organization, or its functionality is reduced to the point that it is no longer reliable or productive.

> **scale up** - increase proportionally; "scale up the model"
>
> **scale down** - reduce proportionally; "The model is scaled down"

[ http://www.thefreedictionary.com/scale+up ]